# java : How to have a good indentation?

Tags: java, coding-style, word-wrap

I would like to follow conventions including that not exceed 80 characters per line.

I downloaded the PDF explaining the naming class, variables, and speaking a bit of wrapping but it's still light.

It is stated:
- break after a comma 
- break before an operator
- prefer high level breaks to lower

But how to manage a simple case as this one :

```
File logDir = new File(PropertiesLoader.getProperty(SpecificConstant.AdminStorageProperty.LOG_FOLDER.getValue()));
```

I am tempted to wrap after the parenthesis of getProperty.

If we cut before an operator, must we do that for all the following operators?
I often see this code:

```
String value = SpecificConstant
    .AdminStorageProperty
    .LOG_FOLDER
    .getValue();
```

What is the better way to wrap lines ?

Thank you.

Comment: IMHO the 80 characters per line is a little dated.  However, long lines can also be a headache, producing code that is difficult to read.  The important thing is to produce code that is easily readable by yourself and others.  I often leave the "." on the previously line, but this more of "feel" I have then a rule.  I also tend to group by logic groups where applicable, but again, this more a feel then a rule...

Answer (score 6):

I use the default setting of my IDE so it will auto-format my code as I check it in or when I ask it to.  I rarely manually format code.

I would write

```
 File logDir = new File(PropertiesLoader.getProperty(SpecificConstant.AdminStorageProperty.LOG_FOLDER.getValue()));
```

as (Using the introduce variable refactoring in my IDE)

```
 String logProp = SpecificConstant.AdminStorageProperty.LOG_FOLDER.getValue();
 File logDir = new File(PropertiesLoader.getProperty(logProp));
```

I use a proportional font in my IDE making a 80 character limit less meaningful ;) It is usually more like 200 character limit for me.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, 80 width is a bit outdated of the times when the screen would read best with 80 becasue of low resolution then .

I use 120 as the default width within IDE and it formats to perfectly readable code.

```
File logDir = new File(PropertiesLoader.getProperty(SpecificConstant.AdminStorageProperty.LOG_FOLDER.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Code Conventions for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) by Oracle